# Only one user can enter login by the Android SQLite

Tags: android

I have created 3 user accounts, but only the first account will able to login to the system. If I enter the second and third username along with the password error displayed username or password error. I don't know why. Here is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMH1n.jpg)

```
public  void  login()
{
    String user = ed1.getText().toString();
    String pass = ed2.getText().toString();
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("pos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("select * from user ",null);

    resultSet.moveToFirst();
            String username = resultSet.getString(1);
            String password = resultSet.getString(2);
            SharedPreferences.Editor sp = getSharedPreferences(username, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            sp.putString("uname", username);
            if (user.equals("") && pass.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password))

            {
                Intent i = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("uname", username);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                ed1.requestFocus();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: you can store flag(boolean) into shared preference . and check it at time of login.

Comment: can you write the code it is more helpful

Comment: clear you sharedpreferences while logging out .maybe that would be the problem.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();   this is the code i worte for clear it is working well. but when i am login again same name should shown

Comment: @Nisa you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `moveToFirst()` method which returns the first non-null row in the table from the query you requested. And you are getting all the rows from your current query.

Below is the procedure you can follow to get a successful login with any user.

```
public  void  login()
{
    String user = ed1.getText().toString();
    String pass = ed2.getText().toString();



    if (user.equals("") || pass.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (null!=checkUser(user,pass))

    {
        String userFromDb=checkUser(user,pass);

        Intent i = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("uname", userFromDb);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ed1.setText("");
        ed2.setText("");
        ed1.requestFocus();
    }
}

public String checkUser(String name, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM user WHERE name=? AND password=?",new String[]{name,pass});
    if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String username = cursor.getString(1);
        String password = cursor.getString(2);
        SharedPreferences.Editor sp = getSharedPreferences("username", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        sp.putString("uname", username);
        sp.apply();
        cursor.close();
        return username;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use

```
   String userName = getSharedPreferences("username",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("uname","");
```

to get username on main activity

**Please don't forget to change the column name with respect to your table**

Comment: ya it is working but the SharedPreferences only show first account username only. if login with second and third accounts SharedPreferences user name display on the MainActivity first account name. it is login in successfully problem with SharedPreferences user name

Comment: i did this. first account username only shown .          SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String txt = sp.getString("uname","person");

               t1.setText(txt); this how set the SharedPreferences  Mainactivity

Comment: please show me how are you saving data in sharedprefrences in login ctivity

Answer (score 0):

You can specify user name in Shared Preference and check it at time of login.

for simplicity create one java file which would be responsible for store and load string value.

sample code:

```
public class SharedUsers {

    SharedPreferences mshared;
    public SharedUsers(Context context) {
        mshared=context.getSharedPreferences("filename",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

     public void setUser(String name){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =mshared.edit();
        editor.putString("UserName",name);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String loadUser(){
        String userName=mshared.getString("UserName","defaultUSerName");
        return userName;
    }

}
```

**IF you already know which user you want to login then set it's 
value in load method's default value.**

```
String userName=mshared.getString("UserName","user u allow to login");
```

In Your MainActivity inside onCreate Initialize object of above mention class.

```
SharedUsers SpUsers=new SharedUsers (MainActivity.this);
```

modify your if-else condition:

```
     else if (user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password))

                {
if(SpUsers.loadUser.contains("value which u write in load method of SharedPreference class"){
                    Intent i = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("uname", username);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
}else {
//handle however u like
}
```

**IF you don't know which User will be login then pass user name while login with your Intent.**

when First User login and directed to MainActivity store user name value in shared Preference, In this case that value would be UserName which is  U need passing it through Intent

```
        SpUsers.setUser("user_name you want to allow login");
```

I hope this Ans is helpful to you.